# Why can we subsitute "foo" for "function (x) { return foo(x); }"

Tags: javascript

I was looking for lesser knows facts about JavaScript and I came across this piece, can anyone explain why the below code

```
function (x) { return foo(x); }
```

can be substituted with

```
foo
```

Tried to figure this out with the little knowledge of JavaScript which I had, but I didn't find the reason. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: I guess you meant function pointers?

Comment: This is not the same! Consider `function foo(x) { ... }; foo.bla = 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is a function that takes one argument and returns whatever the result of `foo` with that argument is. The second is a function which takes one argument (presumably) and returns whatever the result of `foo` with that argument is (because it *is* the `foo` function).

The long version is just a wrapper around `foo` which doesn't add anything.

Answer (score 2):

Because

```
var bar1 = function (x) { return foo(x); };
var bar2 = foo;
```

And then

```
bar1(5);
bar2(5);
```

The first one will execute a function that will call `foo(5)`, the second one will call `foo(5)` directly. Same end result.

Answer (score 1):

`function(x){return foo(x);}` actually is a nameless function which passes x to the function foo. The nameless function will return the result of foo(x) on the line `return foo(x)`
which is the same as calling `foo(x)` at the first place not form inside another function.

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet assumes that `foo` is already a function in the current scope.

When you want to pass `foo` as a callback, you can do so directly:

```
function ITakeACallback(callback) {
    callback(42); // and call it
}

ITakeACallback(foo);
```

So what you did here was pass to `ITakeACallback` an argument that happens to be a callable function; `ITakeACallback` indeed calls it.

Of course we can pass *any* callable function:

```
ITakeACallback(function(x) { return foo(x); });
```

This time we passed a function that accepts an argument, calls `foo` with that argument and returns the result. This is a roundabout way of calling `foo` directly, but the end result is the same.